# If I'm a member of one guild, am I prevented from joining any of the other guilds?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I join the Companions, will that keep me from joining the Thieves Guild? Or the Dark Brotherhood?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nope! There's nothing preventing you from holding leadership positions in all 4 major guilds! (After you finish the respective questlines, that is)

Bard College and the Civil War quests are also fair game (though you *do* have to pick a side in the Civil War).

Answer (score 15):

The only ones that you have to choose between are the empire and the stormcloaks; you can only join one or the other.You can join all the rest without contradiction.

Answer (score 15):

***---Note:  Links may contain spoilers!---***

Most of the details below are available on [UESPWiki](http://uesp.net) under the entry [Skyrim:Factions](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Factions) or in pages linked therein.

The only mutually-exclusive factions in the base game are those that represent the two sides in Skyrim's civil war.

- The [Imperial Legion](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Imperial_Legion), based in [Solitude](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Solitude).
- The [Stormcloaks](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Stormcloaks), based in [Windhelm](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Windhelm).

It's also worth making mention here that your choice of who to follow early in the game ([Ralof](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ralof) or [Hadvar](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hadvar)), when escaping [Helgen](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Helgen), does not determine which of the above groups you are joining.

> The two paths essentially merge in [Riverwood](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Riverwood), when family members of either side will suggest that you take news of Helgen to Jarl [Balgruuf the Greater](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Balgruuf_the_Greater) in [Whiterun](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Whiterun).

The NPC you follow out of Helgen, or one of their family members, will invite you to join their cause.  This will add a quest to your journal, but still does not constitute a binding of your character to that faction.  Afterwards, you're still free to join whichever side (or none) in the war you please.

A quest to join the opposing side can usually be picked up by simply encountering one of their soldiers in a city or camp that they control.  The soldier will suggest that you join their cause, and this will populate that quest in your journal.  Once you've expressly declared your allegiance though, you'll fail the quest for the side that you chose to oppose.

> You still have one more chance to switch sides though, during The Jagged Crown.  Simply deliver the crown to the opposition's leader, and you will join their cause instead.

All that having been said, there's several other factions you can join freely.  Joining any of these will not preclude you from joining the others.  They also do not affect, nor will they be affected by, your choice regarding the war.

- [The Bards College](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bards_College), in Solitude.
- The (Mage's) [College of Winterhold](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:College_of_Winterhold_%28faction%29), on the outskirts of [Winterhold](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Winterhold).
- The [Companions](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Companions), in [Whiterun](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Whiterun).

  - [The Circle](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Circle) - An elite sub-group of The Companions.
- [The Dark Brotherhood](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dark_Brotherhood), west of [Falkreath](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Falkreath).*
- [The Thieves' Guild](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_%28faction%29), in [Riften](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Riften).

  - [The Nightingale Sentinels](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingale_Sentinel) - An elite and secret sub-group of The Thieves' Guild.
- The [Blades](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blades), based out of [Sky Haven Temple](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sky_Haven_Temple) which is east of [Markarth](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Markarth).**

> Near or at the end of the quest lines for most groups, you will generally end up becoming the group's leader.  This also will not affect your ability to join or lead other factions.

*The quest to join The Dark Brotherhood actually starts in Windhelm.

**There is (presuming you pursue the main story's questline to its end) an unavoidable quest which puts you in the middle of a conflict between the Blades and Greybeards.  Your decision (or even a lack thereof) in this matter will restrict you from certain resources available via the faction you have chosen against.  I do not list these as "mutually exclusive" factions though, since you never properly "join" the Greybeards.

---

The [Dawnguard DLC](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dawnguard) adds in two new player-joinable factions, which are also mutually exclusive.

- The [Dawnguard](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dawnguard_%28faction%29), based out of [Fort Dawnguard](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fort_Dawnguard) in [Dayspring Canyon](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dayspring_Canyon).
- The [Volkihar Vampire Clan](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Volkihar_Vampire_Clan), based out of [Volkihar Keep](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Volkihar_Keep) which is northwest of [Solitude](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Solitude).

> Note: While these two factions do ultimately become mutually exclusive, you must follow through some of the initial Dawnguard questline before you are given the option to join the Volkihar.

Answer (score 5):

The only mutually exclusive organizations you have to worry about are in the civil war questline -- if you join up with the stormcloacks, you can't join the imperial army and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But like others say, you can only join the Imperials or Stormcloaks. If you wish to join the others it's your choice. There's no sign that says you can't. It just depends what you want to do.

I leveled up in my warrior class to 100, then I worked on my mage and thief skills (also use the stones they help). Then join a certain guild that works with your skills. After I did every last skill at 100 for mage, thief, and warrior; I got the best armor and spells and now I'm practically invincible. My level is 100, and most of my skills are over 2 legendary, and I have every guild joined.

Comment: "*also sorry for no punctation i just dont do that*" First, welcome to Arqade! Second, please do make the effort in the future (and for the record; punctuation wasn't the only glaring issue). We don't expect complete perfection, but a little effort can go a long way. See also; the [about](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/about) page, the [Help Center](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help), and [How do I write a good answer?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

No limit to joining guilds. The only limitation is Stormcloaks/Imperials. If you are in the Dark Brotherhood, you can join still join the Thieve's Guild, etc.

Comment: Yeah the Dark Brotherhood is my favorite, but it was better in oblivion due to the quests and entertainment and the contracts. I mostly side with the Imperials since they aren't racist.