# Can I join all of the guilds and clans?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I become an imperial legion member can I still join the stormcloaks?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't as they are on the opposite side of a civil war.

Comment: Not without mods

Comment: i believe that side factions you can join them all but factions involved in main quests you have to choose a side if they have an opposing group. ie Imperial or Stormcloak, Dawnguard or Vampires

Comment: Also possible duplicate of: [If I'm a member of one guild, am I prevented from joining any of the other guilds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35285/4797)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to experience all the quests for the Stormcloaks and the Imperial Legion, you need to do a second playthrough. While you have the opportunity to switch allegiances at a few points, that will only affect which set of quests you do afterwards.

However, the five Guild storylines (Companions, Thief Guild, Mage College, Bards College and Dark Brotherhood) are all independent from each other and from the Civil War storyline. You can do all five with the same character if you want to.