# How many "organizations" can you join? Do some block you from joining others?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What guilds are in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34525/what-guilds-are-in-skyrim)
>   [If I'm a member of one guild, am I prevented from joining any of the other guilds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35285/if-im-a-member-of-one-guild-am-i-prevented-from-joining-any-of-the-other-guild)

There are a lot of groups to join in Skyrim, and of course, I just can't make up my mind.

I've begun the  quest chains for the following groups:

- The Companions
- The Legion
- The Stormcloaks
- The Dark Brotherhood
- The Bards College
- The Thieves Guild
- The College of Winterhold

Is it possible to join all groups simultaneously, or is there a limit on how many you can join?

Does joining one group block the other (for example, if I join the Legion, can I still join the Stormcloaks?)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate as this is more broad.  The only restriction that I know of is there is a point when you have to make the decision between the legion and the stormcloaks